# how to add a "default highlighter" message in typeahead?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-typeahead

Currently, I see that in Typeahead, when there is no result from the query it will not show any dropdown list nor any sort of message letting the user know the query returned no result.

Is there a way to have just one result that says something like "there's no result" in the dropdown list when the query is not returning anything?

The best solution I can think of so far is to add a "no result" object into the list of results and just use the matcher to handle the case. But somehow I feel this is bad.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the solution i am currently using is the following.

basically i push an empty object into the list of items but not into the map of objects. this will make the sorter believe there is at least one item in the array. so in highlighter when you try to get the object from the map, the object would be undefined.

```
// sort our results
sorter: function(items) {
    if (items.length == 0) { 
        items.push(new Object()); 
    }
        return items;    
    },

highlighter: function(item) {
    comp = map[item];
    if (typeof comp == 'undefined') {
        return "<span>No Match Found.</span>";
    }
```

note that i am working with an array list of objects not the default array of strings.

good tutorial on that here:
http://tatiyants.com/how-to-use-json-objects-with-twitter-bootstrap-typeahead/

not 100% sure if this is good practice, but it gets the job done.